# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined UglifyJSPlugin in webpack error

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

Already 2 days can't solve the problem.I need to install ***uglifyJsPlugin*** in my **webpack**.But **webpack** throw an **error**

```
webpack.config.js:25
        module.exports.plugins.push(

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Plese help me how i can resolve this issue.?

Here's my **webpack.config.js**

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

module.exports = {
    entry: "./common",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename:"bundle"
    },
    watch:NODE_ENV == "development",

    devtool:NODE_ENV == "development" ? "cheap-inline-module-source-map" : null,

    module: {

        rules: [{
             test: /\.js$/,
             loader:'babel-loader?optional[]=runtime',
             options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
        }]

    }
};

if (NODE_ENV == "production") {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                drop_console:true,
                unsafe:true
            }
        })
        )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't have `plugins` defined in your config.

Add this and you should be good to go

```
plugins: [],
```

You may want to change the exports a bit, like this:

```
var config = {
    entry: "./common",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename:"bundle"
    },
    watch:NODE_ENV == "development",

    devtool:NODE_ENV == "development" ? "cheap-inline-module-source-map" : null,

    module: {

        rules: [{
             test: /\.js$/,
             loader:'babel-loader?optional[]=runtime',
             options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
        }]

    },
    plugins: []
};

if (NODE_ENV == "production") {
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                drop_console:true,
                unsafe:true
            }
        })
    );
}

modules.exports = config;
```